# Swift iOS system notification dismiss calback

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter

**Question:**
Is there a way to detect if you get a system notification and you swipe away the notification banner (e.g. the alarm that triggers a system notification)?

**More practical example:**
In your app, you are doing some stuff and suddenly you get a notification from another app. Instead of tapping on the notification, you swipe up the notification (you dismiss it that way). After doing that, I want to capture that in the app.

**Why:**
Currently, I have a bug in the app, so if I can capture this action, I would be able to fix this bug.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Describe your actual problem (the bug) rather than your attempt on solving it (capturing the notification)

Comment: The bug has something to do with hiding UI elements. In the app we hide certain UI elements after some inactivity of the user. Here we have some complex RxSwift things going on. I just need to know how to be notified that the app is back in the foreground from dismissing this notification. However, the default willEnterForegroundNotification does not work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

When notification appears, the `willResignActiveNotification` won't get called, therefore `willEnterForegroundNotification` won't get called, too.
The best solution here is to catch incoming notification and show the custom view describing this notification instead of system one. Thus, you can detect all actions/timings you need.